# how to merge two arrays in objective c one element at a time?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

i have two NSarrays called value and operator. 
i want to merge them into a third array called equation such that the first element of equation is from value, second from operators, third from value and so on. how can i do it.

Comment: is that both the arrays are having same number of elements?

Comment: no, the element in operator is one less than value. between two values i want an operator.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
 for(int i=0;i<[arrValues count];i++){
        [arrResult addObject:[arrValues objectAtIndex:i]];
        if(i<[arrOperators count])
        [arrResult addObject:[arrOperators objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

Comment: What if `arrOperators` count is more then `arrValues` count? It will not be completely merged

Comment: that's why i'm asking him about those two arrays.he mensioned that " the element in operator is one less than value. between two values i want an operator".

Comment: Oh ok I didn't see the comments sorry. However would it not be best to do it as though there could be more in `arrOperators`?

Comment: @Popeye Yes, ambiguity is always the way to go. Check my answer

Answer (score -1):

I would use an enumerator here since you can use it to control how and when you iterate through array and loop it through until all elements are consumed

Something like:

```
NSEnumerator *valueEnumerator = [values objectEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *operatorsEnumerator = [value objectEnumerator];
id anObject;

do{
    if(anObject = [valueEnumerator nextObject])
        [equation.addObject:anObject];
    if(anObject = [operatorsEnumerator nextObject])
        [equation.addObject:anObject];
}while(equation.count != (values.count + operators.count))
```

Comment: @Popeye Just a clean way of checking for nil. If `[Enumerator nextObject]` is nil then the expression will evaluate to false. I do the same when initializing like `if(self = [super init])` which is just a cleaner way of saying `self = [super init]; if(self != null){}`

Comment: @Popeye No. The if statement only checks for nil in this case because you're handling a reference not primitive data. Putting parenthesis around the expression does nothing but change it's scope toward other expressions in the if statement and since there are no other expressions, it's semantically the same as what I have above.

Comment: @Popeye If you wanted to check for 0 or false then you would have to unwrap the object to get that value and (of course) you can't do that if the reference is nil. Here's an example. Lets say you have a `NSNumber` object. First you can check if its nil `if(myNumber)` then you can check if its 0 `if([myNumber integerValue] == 0)` or `if([myNumber boolValue] == false)` or just `if(![myNumber boolValue])`

Comment: @Popeye Also note `if([myNumber boolValue])` will evaluate to false if the object is nil AND if it the value is false but `if(myNumber)` will only evaluate to false if its nil.

Comment: My answer is the only complete answer...Sunny's won't merge the arrays completely. I'm not sure what's complicated about my answer, you're using an enumerator and you're checking for nil before adding it to the array. This is exactly how apple recommends it [NSArray Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectEnumerator)

Comment: Never mind I forget the mentality at SO is "The quick easy way" not "The right way"...so I guess Sunny's would be the better answer. I voted him up.

Comment: And now this (`"forget the mentality at SO"`) is the reason for me not giving you any upvote, I was seeing how you would take that I wouldn't do it your way before giving a +1 and your response was rude and insulting. This isn't welcome on stackoverflow so if you don't like people questioning your answers you clearly in the wrong place, I have removed my previous comments as I don't want to be involved in a discussion with some who is rude and insulting goodbye.

Comment: @Popeye I see so you care more about "testing" a persons personality than the answer they provide? Grow up dude...I'm not here to make friends with you or make you happy. You deleted your comments because you were wrong and now you're embarrassed. I wouldn't expect this kind of behavior from a prominent member such as yourself... you're deceitful and proud of it. How convenient no one will be able to see your comments now. I have more integrity than that, I don't pretend to be someone I'm not.

Comment: Just because I would do it someone else's way doesn't mean your wrong it just means I prefer the other way. I'm not the person who you need to convince and having a bad attitude just isn't welcome on this site and if you want anyone to take you seriously then you also need to learn to take feedback whether it good or bad. Once you learn that you will do well on here but until then sort the attitude out.

Comment: Please note that I never downvoted as your answer isn't wrong the reason I have upvoted is because of your bad attitude when I told you I would do it the other way. This is my last comment because clearly you don't like feedback and there is no point in having a conversation with someone who is just going to insult me.

Comment: Absolutely. If you're going to tell me my answer is wrong or overly complicated and not provide valid points as to WHY, then you will get a bad attitude. I appreciate feedback when it's productive, not when it's there just to make yourself feel better. Edit: I love the way you keep editing your posts after I respond, but I'll keep mine the way it is. It's the response to what you originally posted. Again. Integrity.